# Declarative spring transactions not being committed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have the following service classes:

```
public class UserLoginServiceImpl implements UserLoginService {

  private UserDAO dao;

  public UserLoginServiceImpl(UserDAO dao) {this.dao = dao; }

  public User login(String userName, String password) {
     User u = dao.findUserByCredentials(userName, password);
     if (u == null) {
         throw new UserNotFoundException();
     }
     return u;
}

public class UserManagementServiceImpl implements UserManagementService {

  private UserDAO dao;

  public UserManagementServiceImpl(UserDAO dao) { this.dao = dao; }

  public void createUser(User u) {
     dao.save(u);
  }
}
```

My service interfaces reside under *com.mysystem.services* package and my service implementations under *com.mysystem.services.impl* package.

I am using hibernate as my jpa implementation and declarative transactions in spring. My configuration file is the following:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="serviceMethod" expression="execution(* com.mysystem.services.impl.*.*(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="serviceMethod"/>
</aop:config>

<!--
    Beans
 -->
<bean id="userDao" class="com.mysystem.dao.UserDAOImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="userLoginService" class="com.mysystem.services.impl.UserLoginServiceImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
</bean>
<bean id="userManagementService" class="com.mysystem.services.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="userDao" />
</bean>
```

Lastly, somewhere in my code i run the following:

```
UserManagementService userManagementService = context.getBean(UserManagementService.class);
userManagementService.createUser(new User("test", "test"));

UserLoginService userLogginService = context.getBean(UserLoginService.class);
User user = userLogginService.login("test", "test");
```

which results in the *login()* method throwing an *UserNotFoundException* because it cannot find the user inserted by *createUser()* previously which means that hibernate will not flush the session between method calls. I can verify this form the console output (i can see hibernate's *create* and *select* statements but not *insert*).

Why isn't the transaction committed soon after the call to *createUser()*? What am i doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Using the @Transactional annotation instead of declarative transactions works. Using @Transactional however is not an option for me. I need to implement declarative transactions.

Below is the spring's debug output:

```
13:03:18,174 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Creating new transaction with name [com.mysystem.services.impl.UserManagementServiceImpl.createUser]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:03:18,175 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1af6a711] for JPA transaction
Hibernate: 
    select
        nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
13:03:18,255 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Initiating transaction commit
13:03:18,255 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1af6a711]
13:03:18,256 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1af6a711] after transaction

    13:03:18,263 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Creating new transaction with name [com.mysystem.services.impl.UserLoginServiceImpl.login]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
    13:03:18,263 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1533badd] for JPA transaction
    Hibernate: 
        /* 
    from
        com.mysystem.domain.User u 
    where
        u.userName = :userName 
        and u.password = :password */ select
            user0_.id as id0_,
            user0_.password as password0_,
            user0_.userName as userName0_ 
        from
            Users user0_ 
        where
            user0_.userName=? 
            and user0_.password=? limit ?
    13:03:18,374 TRACE [main] sql.BasicBinder     - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - test
    13:03:18,374 TRACE [main] sql.BasicBinder     - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - test
    13:03:18,379 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Initiating transaction commit
    13:03:18,379 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1533badd]
    13:03:18,379 DEBUG [main] jpa.JpaTransactionManager     - Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1533badd] after transaction
```

Comment: You can do flush (EntityManager.flush()), If you do this after create call in the service method then user will be visible to get method with out actually committing the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one.

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>

        <tx:method name="createUser" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

Comment: you need a new transaction. and this will give you what you need propagation="REQUIRES_NEW. Can you try and give feedback.

Comment: Nope... didn't work either. The funny thing though is that it WORKS when i'm using the @Transactional annotation instead. I guess that it must be something in my configuration but i can't figure it out at the moment.

Comment: himm.. ok.. can you update your pointcut expression com.mysystem.services.impl.*.*(..) i guess problem is there.

Comment: question: should i define my transactions on the implementation class' methods or the interface?

Comment: you should define for implementation. everything seems okey. i couldnt understand.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem (finally). In my design i chose to inject the EntityManagerFactory using constructor injection. In then used emf in my dao's constructor to create an EntityManager and set it  as the dao instance's member variable. I managed to make it work when i changed my injection strategy to use the @PersistenceContext annotation. I am still not sure why my original strategy did not work but the net result is that it works. I would be interested if anyone could explained this.